# Why does passing in fontSize in pt/rem cause StripeElements.CardElement to jump in size?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm using a StripeElements CardElement in React, passing in base styles as an object [per the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#the-elements-object). When I use `fontSize` using pt/rem, the height of the input jumps to `150px` during the "MM/YY CVC" animating in, before settling to its actual size. When I use em/px, the height either doesn't jump at all or too quickly to notice.

What could be causing this? Why does the behavior seem to change depending on the font size unit I use?

[image: CardElement jumping]

```
const CardElementStyle = {
  base: {
    fontSize: `1em`, // values in pt and rem cause jump, while em and px don't cause jump
    fontFamily: `"Whitney A", "Whitney B", Helvetica, sans-serif`,
    fontStyle: "normal"
  },
  invalid: {
    color: PALETTE.nonInteractiveBackground
  }
};
```

```
<StripeElements.CardElement
    className="cardInput"
    style={CardElementStyle}
    />
```